# The correct way of adding custom query parameter in Solr

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene

I am currently running a Solr client/server pair which is working fine.

However, in some cases the filter query (`fq` parameter) which is sent to Solr is quite large (can be thousands of characters) and can not be trimmed down. As the query parsing takes [only a fraction of the overall time](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201204.mbox/%3CCAN4YXvfMJYKR2ga-jY1x6Cu-tvQx5k9r90LXS1bgPmVD7%3DpjBA%40mail.gmail.com%3E), I want to experiment with zipping this query part and sending it to Solr.

I was thinking of modifying the client so instead of `fq` it uses another parameter (e.g. `zfq`). Solr can then decide - if it receives `zfq`, it uses it and decodes the data into `fq`. Otherwise it should behave as usual.

What is the standard way to achieve the above? Looks like there is `SearchHandler`, `requestHandler`, `<queryParser` (both in solrconfig.xml) and many others and I'm not quite sure what's least intrusive. I'm fairly confident with Lucene/Tomcat but don't know much about Solr data structures.

Comment: Thousands of characters in a single `fq` doesn't seem right. Instead of trying to work around the limitations, ask yourself *why* you're hitting those limitations. Describe your *real* issue.

Comment: The real issue is outside the scope of this question. But if you want to hear it - sure, no problem! The length comes from how permissions are implemented. For customers having wide permission sets, filter query looks like this: "*:* -category:1 AND -category:2 AND ... -category:N". Which is a perfect candidate for compression as the pattern repeats.

Comment: have you seen this JIRA issue about document-level security? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1834

Comment: Thanks for the link, but at this stage I wouldn't be able to change the existing architecture, especially this only being a patch and not part of official Solr distribution. I just want to *experiment*, that's it.

Comment: Have you thought about using this syntax  -category:(1 2 3 4 ... N). That should reduce the string by 90%.  Better than zipping.

Comment: @Evan this works, indeed. And although slightly offtopic, I am happy to award you all bounty points - just move your comment into an answer. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using this syntax -category:(1 2 3 4 ... N). That should reduce the string by 90%. Better than zipping.

Comment: I wish the bounty points hadn't expired, it took a bit too long for you to get the answer posted :(

Answer (score 1):

You can make your Solr container take extremely long urls: [Tomcat here](https://serverfault.com/questions/56691/whats-the-maximum-url-length-in-tomcat), [Jetty here](https://serverfault.com/questions/136249/how-do-we-increase-the-maximum-allowed-http-get-query-length-in-jetty).

If the `fq`s have some default values, you can create a query parser that includes it by default.

```
  <requestHandler name="for_some_queries" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <!-- default values for query parameters -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="fq">MY VERY LONG FQ</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

---

But I agree with Mauricio Scheffer for a better design.

Comment: The `fq` never stays the same so making it default won't help. My actual question is how to extend Solr and not how to solve this problem.

Comment: Bad assumption then :-) But wouldnt increasing the header length (and therefore URL length) of your App container solve your problem?

Comment: I've done that already, but I want to experiment with archiving queries and seeing if this helps to reduce the latency.